# Error using the adonis function

Tags: r, multivariate-testing

I have some data from a toxicity assay. My response variable is `Plutei`, which is the number of normal-shaped larvae (6 replicates), collected:

- from 2 different species
- in 5 different times of the year
- in 3 different sites.

I've treated this larvae with:

- 3 different metals
- each one with 6 different concentrations (to analyse the toxicity).

I want to evaluate the significance of each factor (and their interaction) in the `Plutei` response that I measured, and I wanted to do it with the `adonis` function in the `vegan` package, version 2.2-1.

I've created a data frame like this:

```
Time  Species        Site       Metal  Concentration  Plutei  Replicates
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      78           1
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      78           2
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      77           3
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      80           4
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      80           5
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                60      79           6
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                70      70           1
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                70      69           2
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                70      70           3
T1    Paracentrotus  Antignano  Zn                70      71           4
```

This is `str(mydata)`:

```
str(mydata) 'data.frame': 3241 obs. of 7 variables:
 $ Time : Factor w/ 6 levels "T1","T2","T3",..: 6 1 1
 $ Species : Factor w/ 3 levels "Arbacia","Paracentrotus",..: 3 2
 $ Site : Factor w/ 4 levels "Antignano","Chioma",..: 4 1
 $ Metal : Factor w/ 4 levels "Cd","Cu","Metal",..: 3 4
 $ Concentration: Factor w/ 23 levels "100","100/70",..: 23 15 1
 $ Plutei : Factor w/ 90 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 90 77 77 76
 $ Repl : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 ...
```

When I try to run the `adonis` function,

```
perm <- adonis(Plutei ~ Time * Species * Site * Metal, data = mydata, permutations = 999)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for your reply. I am using vegan 2.2-1 and this is str(mydata)...as you can see, I can't assign "Plutei" as Y variable, and I don't know how to deal with the replicates

Comment: str(mydata)
'data.frame':   3241 obs. of  7 variables:


 $ Time         : Factor w/ 6 levels "T1","T2","T3",..: 6 1 1


 $ Species      : Factor w/ 3 levels "Arbacia","Paracentrotus",..: 3 2


 $ Site         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Antignano","Chioma",..: 4 1


 $ Metal        : Factor w/ 4 levels "Cd","Cu","Metal",..: 3 4


 $ Concentration: Factor w/ 23 levels "100","100/70",..: 23 15 1


 $ Plutei       : Factor w/ 90 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 90 77 77 76 


 $ Repl         : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 ...